# using return list macros with `: list' syntax

Tags: set, stata

I have made a list of variable names and want to check which variables I have excluded. The final line of my best guess does not work because `r(varlist)` is not a macro name:

```
input abc bca cba
1 1 1
end

global mykeeps abc cba

ds
di "`: list local(r(varlist)) - global(mykeeps)'"
```

I know that I could do a clunky three-liner here:

```
local rvarlist "`r(varlist)'"
di "`: list rvarlist - global(mykeeps)'"
macro drop rvarlist
```

I'm asking if there's a more concise (or otherwise better) way.

I've looked through the documentation at `help macrolists` and `help return list`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make your code a "clunky" two-liner if you conclude that you don't need to drop the local macro `rvarlist`. Locals just disappear on their own. I usually don't find the need to explicitly drop them, although I don't mean to say that this is never necessary.

I would worry more about your use of `global`s. Their use can have unintended effects because, unlike `local`s, they don't die out and can collide with other system/program name spaces. Use them only if you *really* know what you're doing

An alternative to your code may be the following, but you lose functionality if you're filtering out variables with `ds`:

```
clear 
set more off

input abc bca cba
1 1 1
end

local mykeeps abc cba
unab myvars: _all

di "`:list myvars - mykeeps'"
```

If you install the user-written command `findname` (SSC by Nick Cox), you get back functionality and allows for direct generation of a local macro. The filtered variable list can be put into a local directly:

```
clear 
set more off

input abc bca cba
1 1 1
end

local mykeeps abc cba
findname, local(myvars)

di "`:list myvars - mykeeps'"
```

See the corresponding help files and also [Speaking Stata: Finding variables](http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0048).

Comment: Thanks, Roberto! `unab` and that `findname` package look very handy. I had been hoping the the "r-class" macros had some secret macro names that could just be plugged in. After all, they are macros... By the way, part of the clunkiness I see in my original code comes from the number of delimiters (parentheses and quote marks), not just the extra lines.

Comment: You can also use `local rvarlist = r(varlist)` and spare the quotes in your original code.

Comment: Regarding my last comment: now I read "Referring to r(macro) without quotes is never a good idea; the feature was included merely for
completeness". See **[R]** stored results which has interesting information.

Comment: Thanks for the incidental and deliberate publicity.... `ds` has morphed in role over its 20-year history from displaying variable names concisely to finding variable names matching some criterion or criteria. It's attributed to me but more importantly an official command, i.e. included in the software distributed by StataCorp. `findname` is my second take, and adds some functionality; it remains user-written, but I regard it as better. All that said, the best single way to put variable names into a macro is `unab` which is dedicated to that purpose.